# Select JSON data and edit it with the same data using NODE.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i'm stuck.. i want to use a data from my json, and edit this json with the same data: (images are better then explication)
my JSON file looks like that:

```
[{
"method": "GET",
"path": "/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "rootPath",
"handler": "generatedApps/avion01/actions.HomeHandler"
},
{
"method": "GET",
"path": "/avions/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "avionsPath",
"handler": "generatedApps/avion01/actions.AvionsResource.List"
}, 
{
"method": "GET",
"path": "/notifications/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "notificationsPath",
"handler": "generatedApps/avion01/actions.NotificationsResource.List"
}, 
{
"method": "POST",
"path": "/notifications/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "notificationsPath",
"handler": 
"generatedApps/avion01/actions.NotificationsResource.Create"
}]
```

and i want to take the param who are in "path" (avions or notification) and create a data named "ressourceName":"(if path == avions or path == notification)"

That should look like this:

```
[{
"method": "GET",
"path": "/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "rootPath",
"handler": "generatedApps/avion01/actions.HomeHandler"
},
{
"ressourceName": "avions",
"method": "GET",
"path": "/avions/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "avionsPath",
"handler": "generatedApps/avion01/actions.AvionsResource.List"
}, 
{
"ressourceName": "notifications",
"method": "GET",
"path": "/notifications/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "notificationsPath",
"handler": "generatedApps/avion01/actions.NotificationsResource.List"
}, 
{
"ressourceName": "notifications",
"method": "POST",
"path": "/notifications/",
"aliases": "",
"name": "notificationsPath",
"handler": 
"generatedApps/avion01/actions.NotificationsResource.Create"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over items and update the item by comparing the path:

```
items.forEach(item => {
  if(item.path === '/avions/') {
    item.ressourceName = 'avions':
  } else if(item.path === '/notifications/') {
    item.ressourceName = 'notifications':
  }
})
```

Comment: if i want to use the path dynamically it's not all the time /avions/ or /notifications/ (it can be /bar/ or /foo/ too)

Comment: like in SQL (SELECT *)  there is something like this ? exemple (if(item.path === '/'****'/') { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

For this case, I am assuming that you are holding it as an array of objects in your node code: `var resources = JSON.parse('your incoming array')`

If so, it is a case of looping through your array and adding the field to each object. Ad the name is the same as the content of your path, you can just strip out the slashes and it should cover you in case any other paths appear

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < resources.length; i++){
 var name = resources[i].path.replace(/\//g, '');
 if(name !== ''){
  resources[i].ressourceName = name;
 }
}
console.log('resources',resources)
```

1. `resources[i].path` is your path in string format
2. `.replace()` replaces occurrences in the path string with another string
3. `/\//g` is a regex to find all forward slashes `/`
4. `''` is the empty string to replace these found slashes with
5. `name !== ''` if the new name is only an empty string (ie path was `"/"`) then do not assign the name

This modifies your initial resources array object by adding the `resourceName` property, but does not change the `.path` property.

Comment: There is an invalid left-hand side in assignement (ReferenceError) on name !== '' && resources[i].ressourceName = name;

Comment: Apologies, have edited it to be a bit more verbose. Alternatively you can use `(name !== '') && resources[i].ressourceName = name;`